# Object cannot access its private data. error : private in this context

Tags: c++

I'm a c++ newbie. I have a simple class which stores a person's name and age.
for some reasons an object of the class cannot access the private data. When I run the code below, I get the error: Test::name is private within this context.

Header File

```
namespace Testing {

    class Test {
        public:
            Test(); // initializes to 0
            Test(int age_, std::string name_);
        private:
            int age;
            std::string name;
    };
}
```

Implementation File:

```
#include <string>
#include "Test.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Testing;

Test::Test(){
    age = 26;
    name = "George";
}

Test::Test(int age_, string name_){
    age = age_;
    name = name_;
}
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Testing;

int main(){

    Test test;    
    cout << test.name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your implementation is not in the Testing namespace.

Comment: private and protected members are not accessed from outside the class while public you can. So you either make name public or use a getter / setter. Remember a class by default its members are private while a structs's are public by default.

Comment: Please format the code

Comment: @drescherjm: There's no need to do so. `using namespace Testing;` is completely sufficient to define the members as they are defined in the OP's code. The class name in member definitions is looked up using regular name lookup. It does find class `Testing::Test` because of the previous `using namespace Testing;`. And it does properly associate definitions with the declarations.

Comment: @Eljay: That's irrelevant. There's no need to explicitly put the definitions into `Testring` namespace. The definitions in the OP's code are made correctly. When you are defining something that has been declared previously, there's no need to explicitly "reopen" the namespace.

Comment: @Eljay, how should I use namespace in the implementation

Comment: @G king: Everything is perfectly fine with the namespace in your code. There's no real need to change anything with regard to namespace. You can rewrite it differently, but it is matter of personal taste. The error in your code has nothing to do with namespaces.

Comment: @AnT • hmm, thank you... I did not know that!  I learned something new today.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to access a private member of your class from `main` function. It is not the "object" that accesses the private data (and it is not clear what you meant by that), it is function `main` that attempts to access that data. Function `main` does not have access to private members of your class. hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

A object cant access the private data directly.
Only the member functions of class can access it.
So try to write a member function(function inside a class) or make variable (age,name) to public like

> class Test{
>
> public:
>
> Test(); // initializes to 0
>
> Test(int age_, std::string name_);
>
> int age;
>
> std::string name;
>
> };

[Refer this for using private data member](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/accessing-data-members.php)

or else create friend functions

[Refer this for using friend functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)

Comment: "Only the member functions of class can access it." Pressumably you mean the class in which members are declared? Strictly speaking, that isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you try to access `private` data (name) so you need to use a public `getter` or make the member data public:

```
std::string Test::getName()const{
    return name;
}
```

And in main:

```
//cout << test.name<< endl;
std::cout << test.getName() << endl;
```